# Is there a hyperlink 'characteristic' for cells in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am creating a macro, and want to know if there is any way to check if a cell has a valid hyperlink in it? I want to just set up a basic if state:

```
If Range("A1").hyperlink = True Then
// don't perform action
Else
// Perform action
End if
```

Obviously the .hyperlink is wrong (right?), is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Excel does support Hyperlink objects. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835563.aspx) can tell you more. If I were you, I would identify all the hyperlinks in the range I'm interested in. Then, I would run the if loop that would fail if (for example) Range A1 was not on the list of cells that have hyperlink objects in them.

Comment: How are your links given? My answer should catch both `=Hyperlink("http://www.google.com","Link")` cells and `http://www.google.com` cells.  Is there another format that's possibly being overlooked?

Comment: For your information. The correct term for what you call _Characteristic_ is _Property_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
If Left(Range("A1").Formula, 7) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
    Debug.print "Link found!"
End If
```

Note the above will work **only** if you're actually using the `=Hyperlink()` formula.  If you have cells that are just hyperlinks with text, `http://www.google.com`, then use this:

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Dim isLink As Boolean
isLink = False

Set rng = Range("A1")

If Left(rng.Formula, 7) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
    isLink = True
ElseIf rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    isLink = True
End If

If isLink Then
    ' If there's a hyperlink, run the code here.
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: is there anyway to check if the link is valid? For example, if the sheet within the excel sheet that the hyperlink links to has been deleted (by another part of the macro... this is part of the macro's normal function) the hyperlink is no longer valid. However, rng.Hyperlinks.count is still 1, because the hyperlink hasn't been removed, though its target isn't valid because it doesn't exist anymore. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: "...the hyperlink is no longer valid." - Do you mean that if you follow the link, it goes to a 404/non existent page?  Or it's not valid for your use?

Comment: Yes I mean that it goes to a 404 pop up saying that the page does not exist

Comment: @AlekPiasecki - that's a different question altogether. However, check out [this page](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/632198-check-if-url-valid.html) though for a possible solution for you